# Añadir elementos a un array en un archivo json en android

Tags: android, json

Necesito añadir un nuevo elemento a un array de un archivo .json que se encuentra en mi carpeta `/raw`, el procedimiento seria algo como copiar el objeto json de un servicio web y pegarlo en el array json del archivo contenido en la carpeta `/raw`.

Answer (score 0):

NO puedes editar un archivo dentro del folder `/raw`, recuerda que tanto el folder `/assets` como `/raw` son únicamente para lectura.
Lo que puedes es realizar una copia del archivo .json ubicado dentro de `/raw` y de esta forma podrás editar la copia y leer los cambios.

Agrego un método que te será de utilidad:

```
private void CopyRawToSDCard(int id, String path) {
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(id);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(path);
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        Log.i(TAG, "copyFile, success!");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "copyFile FileNotFoundException " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "copyFile IOException " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Se llamaría al método de esta forma:

```
   CopyRawToSDCard(R.raw.miarchivo, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/miarchivo.json" );
```

Para leerlo se realizaría de esta forma:

```
  File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/miarchivo.json" );
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, no sabia no se podian modificar los archivos en la carpeta raw, al final di con la solución copindo el json para la memoria interna y de allí modifico los datos...